# Spring Graphql path not found on Docker Container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, graphql

**Hi There**

Everything is working without any problem when application is running on IntelliJ IDEA. Mutation is working fine Query is working fine there is no problem at all. But when application is working on docker container I can't access GraphQL path.  Spring throws an HTTP "404 not found" exception when an application is working on docker container. I literally did not get it what is the problem. Someone could you help me about that? What is the problem?

**Note: Other applications are working fine with POSTMAN except GraphQL application with this docker-compose file. Swagger UI is not seeming on browser. It is also thrown an HTTP 404 Not Found Exception when it is working with docker container [Whitelabel Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E8YV.jpg)**

**Error on Docker Container Request port:8093**

```
   {
        "timestamp": "2023-02-01T19:28:13.384+00:00",
        "status": 404,
        "error": "Not Found",
        "path": "/api/v1/graphql"
    }
```

**Browser picture**

[docker-compose.yaml browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcXv1.jpg)

[localhost browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hBrm.jpg)

**build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.9-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.18'

}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}
def grpcVersion = '1.51.0'
def protobufVersion = '3.19.2'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql-test'

    //GRAPHQL
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux'

    //GRPC
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-netty:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation 'net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter:2.14.0.RELEASE'

    // Log4j
    implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobufVersion}" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins { grpc {} }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}


tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/userDb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=123456

spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true
spring.graphql.graphiql.path=/graphiql
grpc.server.port=9093

spring.graphql.path=/api/v1/graphql
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15672:15672"

  user_db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: user_db
    read_only: true
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_DB=userDb
    expose:
      - "5434"
    ports:
      - "5434:5434"
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
      - /run
      - /run/postgresql
    volumes:
      - postgres-user-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: -p 5434   


  myapp.service:
    image: 'myapp.service'
    container_name: myapp.service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://user_db:5434/userDb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=123456
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      - SPRING_GRAPHQL_GRAPHIQL_ENABLED=true
      - SPRING_GRAPHQL_GRAPHIQL_PATH=/graphiql
      - GRPC_SERVER_PORT=9093
      - SPRING_GRAPHQL_PATH=/api/v1/graphql

    ports:
      - "8093:8080"
    depends_on:
      - user_db
    
volumes:
  postgres-user-db-volume:
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `schema.graphqls` file in your classpath? If so, please note that you may be relying on the default value of the `spring.graphql.schema.locations` property. This default value does not resolve correctly in a Docker container. If the service is unable to load the schema, it will throw a `404` error on the `/graphql` endpoint.

You should explicitly add the location to your graphql schema directory in your `application.properties`.

For example

```
spring.graphql.schema.locations=classpath*:graphql/
```